# Validate is not detected as a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

my html page head has

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

and i can see the file in the network tab

[image]

and i can see the file to

[image]

but the validate() function still unrecognized

[image]

Any ideas, what have i missed?

This is a projet made in asp.net mvc using EntityFrameWorkCore

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting on the question. You're missing a `"` to end the first attribute of the second `script` tag so the library isn't being added to the page.

Comment: you are right but saddly that didn't solve my problem.That " was probably deleted when i was trying to format the code on the post , the code itself was fine on the project

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), you need to apply the validate function on the jQuery object that *$("#form")* returns, not on the HTML node you obtain with *$("#form")[0]*.

Have you tried executing this?

```
$("#form").validate();
```

Comment: in my third print screen i've shown that i tried '$("#form")[0].validate(); ' which i think it's the same. Anyway  i've tried your sugestion but unfortunately still got the same result as before

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to make sure the `jquery.validate.js` is loaded after `jquery-xxx.js` and `jquery-xxx.min.js`.For example,if you see the loading order is `jquery-xxx.min.js`,`jquery.validate.js`,`jquery-xxx.js`,you will get the error `$().validate is not a function`.

You can put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

in Shared/_layout.cshtml like the following:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and don't need to add the scripts to the page you use it.

Secondly,you need to use like

```
$("#myform").validate();
```